# how to make a tuple from array

Tags: python

I've a list of values in an array:

```
 departamentos = ["Piura", "Lima"]
```

And I would like to transform it to:

```
 departamentos = (("Piura", "Piura"), ("Lima", "Lima"),)
```

I've tried this:

```
for i in departamentos:
     mis_departamentos_b  = mis_departamentos + ((i, i))
```

But it only returns the last item as a tuple.

```
mis_departamentos_b
('Lima', 'Lima')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
tuple((x,x) for x in departamentos)
```

---

```
(('Piura', 'Piura'), ('Lima', 'Lima'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides @Claus's answer, you could also use `map`:

```
 tuple(map(lambda d: (d, d), departamentos))
```

---

```
(('Piura', 'Piura'), ('Lima', 'Lima'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do get the same as follows.

```
>>> departamentos = ["Piura", "Lima"]
>>> t = tuple(((name, ) * 2 for name in departamentos))
>>> t
(('Piura', 'Piura'), ('Lima', 'Lima'))
>>>
```

> Detailed:

```
>>> departamentos = ["Piura", "Lima"]
>>>
>>> t = ((name, ) * 2 for name in departamentos)
>>> t
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001D13A5F8518>
>>>
>>> tuple(t)
(('Piura', 'Piura'), ('Lima', 'Lima'))
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue is in your variables. Below is modified code. You are using mis_departamentos_b and you are only assigning to it, so previous value of Plura Plura is overwritten by next value of Lima Lima

```
departamentos = ["Piura", "Lima"]
mis_departamentos = ()
for i in departamentos:
     mis_departamentos  = mis_departamentos + ((i, i))
print(mis_departame
```